# Border colours in IE10 incorrect - all other browsers OK

Tags: colors, border, internet-explorer-10

I have noticed that all my table borders when viewed in IE10 are showing up as dark grey / black, no matter what colour I set them within the HTML code.

How do I overcome this? Why is it doing it? The borders are appearing the correct colour in all other browsers.

Here is an example - **http://www.xplore.net.au/programs.htm**

Note the ugly black border which is actually set at:
`<table width="950"  border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#dcdcdc">`

Answer (score 3):

IE10 no longer supports the `bordercolor` HTML attribute. Using presentational attributes on markup, such as tables, is deprecated, and sees less use these days. To guarantee things work in the future, you should consider switching to styling with CSS.

In this case, to get it working you could remove the `border` and `bordercolor` attributes, and add the styling via CSS instead.

See this example showing `bordercolor` no longer working in IE10, and the equivalent in CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/kfxdh/

```
#css {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Note that unlike the `border` and `bordercolor` properties, this does not put borders around the individual cells. if you wish to emulate that, you could do the same by adding a border to the tds:

```
#css td {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kfxdh/1/

Comment: +1, but `#css td` is a BAD IDEA in case of nested tables and also won't affect `<th>` elements. Prefer `#css>tr>td,#css>thead>tr>td,#css>tbody>tr>td,#css>tfoot>tr>td,#css>tr>th,#css>thead>tr>th,#css>tbody>tr>th,#css>tfoot>tr>th` instead.

Comment: yeah, it was just an example. In most likelihood the OP wouldn't want borders around every cell.

Comment: Well, that's what `border="1"` does.

Comment: true, but if you look at the actual web page, it does’t have borders on every cell.

Answer (score 0):

In IE10, child elements like tables inherit the color from parent tags like body tag. I also had the same issue in which my table borders are coming as RED, but when I removed the color attribute from BODY tab it worked for me.
Please try.